# javascript: random color generator with a roof and floor

Tags: javascript, math, colors

Hi I was playing around with math random the other day and made an RGB color generator and successfully was able to use a text input to limit the roof of the random number, but was unable to get the floor working. Here is the JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/synthet1c/3KR83/

and here is the Javascript function I made

```
function randomColor(){

    var roof =  document.getElementById('textRoof').value,
        floor = document.getElementById('textFloor').value;

    var r = Math.floor((Math.random()*roof)+floor);
    var g = Math.floor((Math.random()*roof)+floor);
    var b = Math.floor((Math.random()*roof)+floor);


    if (r < 10) { var r = "0" + r}
    if (r < 100) { var r = "0" + r};

    if (g < 10) { var g = "0" + g};
    if (g < 100) { var g = "0" + g};

    if (b < 10) { var b = "0" + b};
    if (b < 100) { var b = "0" + b};

    document.getElementById('header').style.color= "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"
    document.getElementById('text').value = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"

}
```

This is just for the sake of learning it, but any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3KR83/3/ like this?

Comment: Note: var is only scoped to the *function* level. It is not correct to declare a new var inside of an if block--it does not work. I recommend that you use something like [jshint.com](http://jshint.com) to validate your javascript. You will learn a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var roof =  document.getElementById('textRoof').value,
  floor = document.getElementById('textFloor').value;

// convert the string values to integer values
roof = parseInt(roof);
floor = parseInt(floor);

var r = Math.floor((Math.random()*(roof-floor))+floor);
var g = Math.floor((Math.random()*(roof-floor))+floor);
var b = Math.floor((Math.random()*(roof-floor))+floor);
```

[live example](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/3KR83/1/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your **floor** was a text. You need a integer - parseInt.
2. You can simplify your color getting by using bit shift.

   ```
   function randomColor(){

   var roof =  parseInt(document.getElementById('textRoof').value),
       floor = parseInt(document.getElementById('textFloor').value);

   var r = floor + Math.floor(Math.random()*(roof-floor));
   var g = floor + Math.floor(Math.random()*(roof-floor));
   var b = floor + Math.floor(Math.random()*(roof-floor));

   var color = ((r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16);

   document.getElementById('header').style.color= 
       "#000000".replace(new RegExp(".{"+color.length+"}$"), color);

   document.getElementById('text').value = "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")"

   }
   ```

Comment: Using `color.toString(16)` alone will not work. Consider the color `#000FFF`, which is a full-color blue with the slightest green tint: when you use `.toString()` on the decimal value for that, you'll get `#FFF` which the browser will interpret as white.

Comment: Thx @ErikE, i've fixed. Now with padding zero.